# How to change the image on a webpage by the time of day using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image, time

I've seen variations of this before but I keep running into roadblocks that are causing headaches.

What I want to do is change a banner image on my web page by the time of day in my region (Pacific Standard) by using JavaScript. I get the main idea that I have to do for the function, but I'm confused on how I can import an image or add an image into the webpage when it wasn't there before.

```
    function timeOfDayImage() {
    var now = new Date;
    var timeNow = now.getHours();

       if(timeNow < 8 || timeNow > 10){
            code
       }
       else {
          code
       }
```

Any help?

Comment: take a look at document.getElementbyId

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358155/changing-background-based-on-time-of-day-using-javascript

Answer (score 1):

I'd give your body element a class:

```
function timeOfDayImage() {
    var now = new Date();
    var timeNow = now.getHours();

    if (timeNow < 8 || timeNow > 10) {
        body.classList.add('it-is-time');
    }
}
```

And change the element with CSS:

```
body #banner {
    background-image: url('images/one.png');
}

body.it-is-time #banner {
    background-image: url('images/two.png');
}
```

Comment: [Dirty I.E. strikes again with no support with < version 10 on classList](http://caniuse.com/classlist). Why...why do we let it be a browser.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to import an image into the web page. Set the `src` attribute of the banner image to the URL of new image and the browser will load it for you

```
function timeOfDayImage() {
   var now = new Date;
   var timeNow = now.getHours();
   if(timeNow < 8 || timeNow > 10){
      document.getElementById('image').src='http://www.images.com/banner1.jpg';
   }
   else {
      document.getElementById('image').src='http://www.images.com/banner2.jpg';
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an ID in your banner image like so:

```
<img id="banner" alt="Something appropriate" />
```

And then use `getElementById` to select the reference from the `DoM`. Change the source (`src`) attribute with the variable reference of the selected element. If you want, you can change the `alt` attribute also, to ensure that the changed image is descriptive for screen readers.

```
function timeOfDayImage() {
    var now = new Date;
    var timeNow = now.getHours();
    var img = document.getElementById("banner");
    if (timeNow < 8 || timeNow > 10) {
        img.src="someimage.png";
        img.alt="Something equally appropriate";
    } else {
        img.src="someimage.png";
        img.alt="Something appropriate here too";
    }
}

timeOfDayImage();
```

[Fiddle with a non-existent image(proof of concept)](http://jsfiddle.net/HJkuG/1/)

Comment: Thanks! This worked like a charm, but the time is always done in military time correct? I'm trying to set images to display between 6-8am and 7=9 pm. Wouldn't they be...

Comment: else if (timeNow <= 8 || timeNow => 6){
                img.src="mustache.JPG";
                img.alt="something equally appropriate";

Comment: @FlashGordon Just adjust the PM hours by +12 and use the same concept

Comment: I'm sorry to say that my code isn't wanting to work with these different blocks. [link]http://jsfiddle.net/HJkuG/1/ This is what I got